# ¿Hacia cuándo se extinguió la palabra 'Sage'?

Tags: historia, sustantivos, español-medio

Leyendo acerca de la vida de Francis Drake, pasé por el "Discurso de Francis Drake" escrito por Juan de Castellanos, escrito aprox. en la década de 1590. En este, el inglés es descrito como:

> (...)Astuto dizen ser y varón *sage*

Después de unos minutos por google y el mapa de diccionarios, encontré como definición de *sage* en este último, en donde aparece la versión de 1780 de la siguiente forma:

> s. m. ant. Lo mismo que SABIO, Ó MUY AVISADO y ASTUTO. *sagax*

Si en poco menos de 200 años el vocablo ya es antiguo, parece que la palabra vendría en un uso moderado para cuando escriben el Discurso. ¿En los primeros diccionarios (Covarrubias, Autoridades o muy probablemente en el de Nebrija) aparece el término? ¿Hasta cuando se reporta en los Corpus lingüisticos la palabra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La palabra *sage* estuvo en el diccionario de la RAE hasta 1992, desapareciendo en la edición de 2001. Y mucho ha durado, porque fíjate lo que decía el *Autoridades* allá por 1739:

> SAGE. s. m. Lo mismo que Sabio, ò mui avisado, y astúto. Trahele Nebrixa en su Vocabulario; pero dice que es antiquado.

Es decir, hablamos de que Nebrija, que publicó sus vocabularios a finales del siglo XV y principios del XVI, ya avisaba de que el término estaba anticuado. En el CORDE se encuentran algunos usos pero parecen ser textos en francés sobre todo (idioma del cual proviene la palabra, según la etimología indicada en la edición de 1992 del diccionario de la RAE). De entre los textos en español podemos citar este:

> *Sagire es sentir aguda mente. Assi que se dizen sages los que quieren muchas cosas saber: & dize se presagire quien antes lo siente que se ofresca el acaesçimiento dela cosa.*
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).

Curioso que el texto en realidad es una anotación en la entrada de otra palabra: *presagiar*. Es decir, que *sage* no tenía entrada propia, apareciendo solo en esa aclaración. No encuentro texto alguno que use la palabra por esas fechas, aunque sí algo antes:

> *Ya pues, si deve en este grand lago
>
> guiarse la flota por dicho del sage,
>
> vos dexaredes aqueste viage
>
> fasta ver día non tan aziago.*
>
> Juan de Mena, "Laberinto de fortuna o las trescientas", 1444 (España).

Claro que esto es poesía y el uso de la palabra podría ser más por arte que otra cosa. Más atrás nos encontramos esto:

> *Et la ora vno de los sages del rey vino detras a Rotari et firiolo en la cabeça.*
>
> Juan Fernández de Heredia, "Traducción de Breviarium ab urbe condita, de Eutropio. París, Arsenal, ms. 8324", 1377 - 1399 (España).

Y el caso más antiguo, pero que resulta que también es parte de un poema:

> *Así el loco como el sage,
>
> todos la tienen por de paratge.*
>
> Anónimo, "Vida de Santa María Egipcíaca", c 1215 (España).

Y no te creas que se encuentran muchos más casos, aparte de estos. Es decir, que era una palabra muy culta, poco usada incluso allá por el siglo XIII, y que apenas ha quedado registrada más allá del siglo XV salvo en diccionarios y textos modernos que la usan a sabiendas de que es un anacronismo o como galicismo, como el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Yo creía que mis palabras iban convenciéndola poco a poco de que lo más "sage", es decir, lo más cuerdo y lo más práctico, era volver al lado de su novio; [...].*
>
> Enrique Gómez Carrillo, "Los primeros pasos en París", 1919 (Guatemala).

Nótese que por el título se deduce que la acción transcurre en Francia, por lo que es probable que la palabra se use como expresión importada del francés.

Comment: Lo curioso es que (según muestra el mapa de diccionarios) es una palabra 'fantasmal'... aparece y desaparece en ciertas versiones del diccionario (en 1992 reapareció, después que estuviera en 1817 y 'desapareciera' por varias versiones, aunque no sabría con exactitud en cual sí estuvo y en cual no, y desde ahí no la hemos vuelto a ver...)